# Python pkg_resources cannot find module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this project template generated from [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter). It's a `PyQT5` project template.

So I thought about just trying to run it. And I got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'socket_messenger.images'; 'socket_messenger' is not a package
```

So here's how it looks like:

```
[dabljues@manjaro socket_messenger]$ tree
.
├── LICENSE
├── pytest.ini
├── README.rst
├── setup.py
└── socket_messenger
    ├── images
    │   ├── ic_help_black_48dp_1x.png
    │   ├── ic_insert_drive_file_black_48dp_1x.png
    │   ├── ic_open_in_new_black_48dp_1x.png
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── socket_messenger.cpython-37.pyc
    ├── socket_messenger.py
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_socket_messenger.py

5 directories, 14 files
[dabljues@manjaro socket_messenger]$ cd socket_messenger/
[dabljues@manjaro socket_messenger]$ ls
images  __init__.py  __pycache__  socket_messenger.py  tests
[dabljues@manjaro socket_messenger]$ python socket_messenger.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socket_messenger.py", line 131, in <module>
    main()
  File "socket_messenger.py", line 121, in main
    window = Messenger()
  File "socket_messenger.py", line 20, in __init__
    'ic_insert_drive_file_black_48dp_1x.png')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1142, in resource_filename
    return get_provider(package_or_requirement).get_resource_filename(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 359, in get_provider
    __import__(moduleOrReq)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'socket_messenger.images'; 'socket_messenger' is not a package
[dabljues@manjaro socket_messenger]$
```

The line, that throws the error (with followup) (it's the last line):

```
import sys

import pkg_resources

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAction, QApplication, QDesktopWidget, QDialog, QFileDialog,
                             QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QMainWindow, QToolBar, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)


class Messenger(QMainWindow):
    """Create the main window that stores all of the widgets necessary for the application."""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Initialize the components of the main window."""
        super(Messenger, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(1024, 768)
        self.setWindowTitle('Messenger')
        window_icon = pkg_resources.resource_filename('socket_messenger.images',
                                                      'ic_insert_drive_file_black_48dp_1x.png')
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? Should I maybe run this python file from a different directory or something?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you cd into `socket_messenger` directory:
python will search `socket_messenger/images` inside `socket_messenger`.

Try to move `socket_messenger.py` outside, for example in the parent directory.

And probably you have to do this for getting the resource pathname:

```
window_icon = pkg_resources.resource_filename('socket_messenger',
                     'images/ic_insert_drive_file_black_48dp_1x.png')
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess I can try that, but why does it render this template that way then? I mean, moving files around is no problem for me, but I wanted to follow a certain convention of project structure

Comment: If moving files is not an option, Another possibility it is to run `python socket_messenger/socket_messenger.py` from the root dir, it should work.

Comment: Last bit: I cannot try this code, but it seems to me that the right usage with the above invocation should be `pkg_resources.resource_filename('images','ic_insert_drive_file_black_48dp_1x.png')`